# why does javascript reorder data I get from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ajax to get some data from server and I get them back in this format:

[image]

however when I print this data in javascript it gets printed ascending by id instead of descending like the data I recieved.

when I print it here it is how it looks:
[image]

it self orders everything in ascending order by letter and number, why does it do this?

Here is my code:

```
        $.ajax("{{route("backend.blog.categories.getparents")}}", {
            method: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("result.categories: " + result.categories);
```

I use this data to populate a select box and I need it to be in the same order I recieve it in and not ordered by javascript automatically. How do I do this?

```
$.each( result.categories, function( key, value ) {
    console.log("key: " + key);
    if(key != exclude){
        parentCategories += '<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>';
    }
});
```

code on the server side:

```
$parentCategories = array();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $parentCategories += [$category->id => $category->title];
}

if($categories){
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'categories' => $parentCategories,
```

Comment: If you want guaranteed order a plain object is the wrong thing. You need an array not a plain object. Object keys have no guaranteed order.

Comment: can you explain more about what you mean with array? I thought I was sending an array, I updated my question with serverside code where I show that I send back an array or am I misstaken?

Comment: PHP (assumed from the last snippet) merges both "arrays" (ordered elements accessed by index) and "associative arrays" (values accessed by named keys) into `array()`. JavaScript, on the other hand, separates them into distinct types – `Array` and `Object`, respectively.

Comment: what can I do about this? How do I send json data back so that it appears as array to javascript?

Comment: Do you need the `key` value preserved, or do you simply need the order of values preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON - the notation you're using - doesn't have an order. If you want to give it a specific order you will have to save that explicitly or use an array. Either way, although according to the spec the order is not guaranteed, modern browsers in general do keep the order. Numeric *looking* keys however form a weird exception that you found now.

```js
let orderKept = {"a2": "a", "a1": "b"};
let orderNotKept = {"2": "a", "1": "b"};
console.log(orderKept, orderNotKept);
```

Example way how this would typically be done properly (guaranteed to work by the spec and not just browser implementations) is an array of objects where every object has its own `id` property.

Of course you could move away from JSON, but keep the same notation and build your own parser, however I would definitely not recommend that.

Comment: it's each function that goes through them and prints them in ascending order actually. What can I do about it?

Comment: JSON has nothing to do with it, that is merely a string representation of data. The issue is Object keys have no guaranteed iteration order when using a for in or Object.keys which $.each probably uses for objects. The solution, as you stated, is to use the correct object an array. If an array is used on the server side it will maintain the correct order when serialized on the client b

Comment: can you explain more about what you mean with array? I thought I was sending an array, I updated my question with serverside code where I show that I send back an array or am I misstaken?

Comment: @ste2425 As I knew that JS does save order in most - if not all - JavaScript implementations I figured that the information was lost during the parsing. Instead it turns out javascript implementations (not the spec) sort numeric looking strings whilst keeping the order for non-numeric-looking strings.

Comment: You should delete that last comment suggesting they write their own parser ; that's asking for trouble and incompatibility

Comment: So could you change your answer as its not the JSON format nor the JSON parser but JavaScript itself, as you've said.

Comment: @ste2425 it's the format *kind of*. Although the JSON spec doesn't mention it outright the spec is based on JS objects obviously and the order information isn't guaranteed anymore from the second you go from PHP to a string of JSON (as according to the JSON spec parsers are allowed to, but don't have to save the order).